# Join on PY date range in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below two tables:

[image]

[image]

~ What I am looking to do: I want to append the Price from Table 2 (t2) to Table 1 (t1), by joining on Quantity and YYYY_MM. Each t2.price was active in a certain time range (t2.Price_Active_Date_From and t2.Price_Active_Date_To), and the t1.Order_YYYYMM should fall within this range. Year 9999 indicates that the price has no end date yet, and is therefore still active. I also want to find which price was active 1 year prior to the order date

So the result should look like:
[image]

What I have tried below so far, which works to get the Price_Active_At_Order, but  I am not sure how to get Price_Active_PY when my date values are strings:

```
select distinct
t1.Product_NR,
t1.Customer,
t1.Quantity,
t2.Price as Price_Active_At_Order,
t1.Order_YYYYMM as Order_Date

from Table_1 t1
join Table_2 t2 on t1.Product_NR = t2.Product_NR
                and t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
                and t1.Order_YYYYMM between t2.Price_Active_Date_From and t2.Price_Active_Date_To
```

Comment: Why is `Price_Active_PY`=120 in row where `Customer`='Y'

Comment: Price_Active_PY is meant pull the price that was active 1 year prior to the Order_Date. Meaning, 1 year prior to the order date (in row two this is 202103), the price was 120. The price of 120 for product_nr 10023 was active between 202101 and 202205.

 I renamed the PY column to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the second table again with 1 year prior date to fetch the prior year's data -

```
select distinct
t1.Product_NR,
t1.Customer,
t1.Quantity,
t2.Price as Price_Active_At_Order,
t3.price as Price_Active_1Year_PriorOrder,
t1.Order_YYYYMM as Order_Date

from Table_1 t1
join Table_2 t2 on t1.Product_NR = t2.Product_NR
                and t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
                and t1.Order_YYYYMM between t2.Price_Active_Date_From and t2.Price_Active_Date_To
join Table_2 t3 on t1.Product_NR = t3.Product_NR
                and t1.Quantity = t3.Quantity
                and TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t1.Order_YYYYMM, 'YYYYMM'), -12), 'YYYYMM') between t3.Price_Active_Date_From and t3.Price_Active_Date_To
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join twice on `Table2` and use a `LATERAL` join with `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` (which would prevent getting multiple rows and needing to use `DISTINCT`):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT price
         FROM   table2 t2
         WHERE  t1.product_nr = t2.product_nr
         AND    t1.quantity   = t2.quantity
         AND    t1.order_yyyymm BETWEEN t2.price_active_date_from
                                    AND t2.price_active_date_to
         ORDER BY t2.price ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t2
       ON (1 = 1)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT price AS price_ly
         FROM   table2 t2_ly
         WHERE  t1.product_nr = t2_ly.product_nr
         AND    t1.quantity   = t2_ly.quantity
         AND    TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t1.order_yyyymm, 'YYYYMM'), -12), 'YYYYMM')
                                BETWEEN t2_ly.price_active_date_from
                                    AND t2_ly.price_active_date_to
         ORDER BY t2_ly.price ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t2_ly
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | PRODUCT_NR | CUSTOMER | QUANTITY | ORDER_YYYYMM | PRICE | PRICE_LY |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10023 | X | 20 | 202104 | 250 | 300 |
> | 10023 | Y | 10 | 202203 | 120 | 120 |
> | 10334 | X | 1 | 202204 | 30 | 25 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c750f56f73a158cf72cae4d107913631)*